# Foundation Tabs - include content that's outside of tabs main div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I need some way of hacking Foundations Tab functionality so that I can include a div that is external to the tabs-content div.  I have limited control over the HTML mark-up and therefore need to manipulate this using JQuery / CSS.  Can anyone help?

```
<dl class="tabs" data-tab>
  <dd class="active"><a href="#panel_details">Details</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#panel_desc">Description</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#panel_image>Images</a></dd>
</dl>
<div class="tabs-content">
  <div class="content active" id="panel_details">
    <p>First panel content goes here...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel_desc">
    <p>Second panel content goes here...</p>
  </div>
   <!-- #panel_image should go here butI can't change the markup-->
</div>


<!--lots more HTML code inbetween-->


  <div class="content" id="panel_image">
    <p>Third panel content goes here...</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Jquery `detach` & `append` on load would do it wouldn't it? I confess my JQ skills are poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My jquery skills are poor but a JQuery `append` function seems to work.

Define the 'extra' div anywhere then

JQuery

```
$( ".tabs-content" ).append( $( "#panel_image" ) );
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/bBAan)

Comment: Thats works well on the demo, can't seem to get it working on my page though with the tabs